# how to write sensu checks for C# wcf api

Tags: c#, wcf, monitoring, sensu

Is anyone aware of a general pattern or resource(website,book,presentation?) that lays out a suggested way to instrument a wcf service using sensu checks? my group is gearing up to start the mandatory move to sensu, but I'm not certain what general format/pattern would be best to instrument our wcf service?

I'm thinking that I'll just add method(s) to the service that is a 'health check' and have that respond and write checks against that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't know about writing anything WCF-specific, but look at it in broader terms: you're hosting a web service in a web server that runs on .NET.

Things you can check if you look at it that way:

- Is the webserver responding to requests (perform a GET to the .svc)?
- Does the Application Event Log contain error entries for .NET?
- Does *your* application log contain error entries for the application?

Comment: Thank you for responding, I appreciate it. I guess I was worrying a bit much and looking at this too narrowly - Currently we have a home-made library that copies error logs into one place, I can extend that to drop them into sensu as well.